# Home page design for an e-commerce website

Tags: user-expectation, homepage

I am working on an online marketplace, similar to ebay, where users can post ads or browse and buy products.

The home page of my website is inspired by Google's home page. I has a minimalist design, as shown below:

[image]

I am wondering if it would be better to add a title to the home page to make it clear that this website is an e-commerce website, something like below:

[image]

Do you think the additional of header is a good option?

Comment: The first image (without text below search box) is **making me think** - "What is it?, What should I do here?, What should I search? etc." But the second image (with text below search box) makes me think **less**. Well, google has nothing below the seach box, because everyone knows it. Also, you can try removing the text and making your search box placeholder more descriptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the site is similar to eBay or the design of the homepage is inspired by Google, doesn't mean the company you are working for has the same level of popularity.

In other words, opening a page with a search engine without knowing for sure what to search for or what the page is about can generate uncertainty in the user to the point of wanting to leave the site immediately.

---

Every company in its beginning has (or should have) a corporate image project that supports all its communication pieces. Regarding the logo, it usually comes with its corresponding **tagline**:

- Nike → Just do it
- Adidas → Impossible is Nothing
- Pepsi → That's What I Like
- Apple → Think Different

In consolidated and highly popular companies, the tagline usually refers to the quality of their products or the company's philosophy (*See some [tagline types](https://medium.com/the-juice/the-5-most-effective-types-of-taglines-d8513e8d03b0)*). None of these companies have their tagline as the title of the website because they have other mass media to promote it. But they all have a tagline, even Google and eBay (Google search: "`company name` + tagline")

There are others that do have it on the web, following the corporate guidelines:

[image: Penguin]

<sub>*Source [penguin.com](https://www.penguin.com/)*</sub>

Or adapted to the web page layout:

[image: Michelin]

<sub>*Source [michelin.com](https://www.michelin.com/en/)*</sub>

In recently created companies or those that don't have massive popularity, the tagline usually indicates the type of product: *descriptive tagline* and it's shown in all media until, if possible, creating collective knowledge. The exception is the type of company whose product is implied: a pizzeria.

The example in the question has a very good descriptive tagline at the marketing level:

> #### SHOPLESS
>
> ###### THE FREE ONLINE MARKETPLACE FOR KIWIS

Personally, I would not hesitate a single second to include it on the homepage and give it the corresponding importance. My question is only about the location. As it stands now and from the type of design, it looks more like a search field warning. I would consult the corporate designer. If they don't exist, I would first work on the **graphic relationship between the company logo and its tagline** and then I would see its adaptation to other media, such as the web.

Answer (score 0):

Design for the future, like when you have many more categories and products are being ordered, reviewed, added, etc. Just visualize how much more data you will have to play with.

There is a reason why e-commerce websites show featured products, on-sale items and popular items in your area, etc.

Showing products/categories below the search bar, with sections as described above with thumbnails of products with details and an order/buy button will automatically show the users what the site is about.